# C# datagridview from linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I am trying to make a datagridview in a new form and list only the movie in the datagridview which is selected in the form1 bindingsourced listbox.

```
public partial class modosit : Form
    {
        Db1Entities db;
        public modosit(Db1Entities db)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.db = db;
            var q = (from s in db.Movies where s.Movietitle == (string)lBfilmlista.SelectedValue select s).First();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
```

The listbox is public and i still get the error:does not exist in the current context.
where:deletegate system.func......   does not take 1 arguments

Comment: have you check your designer for `lBfilmlista` ? maybe `lBfilmlista` has been deleted from your designer, and try to get out `(string)lBfilmlista.SelectedValue` from your query

Answer (score 0):

```
string local=lBfilmlista.SelectedValue;

var q = (from s in db.Movies where s.Movietitle == local select s).First();
```

I Hope this will work.

Comment: no. this code not even exist and i have error in the linq

Comment: try this

dataGridView1.DataSource=q.ToList();

Comment: as i said i get error at the listbox The listbox is public and i still get the error:does not exist in the current context. where:deletegate system.func...... does not take 1 arguments

Comment: Hey DOnt use listbox value into your linq query 

try to put it in some local variable and use that local variable into your linq query

i hope this will help